# (solved) Mule 4 - Sending Payload After Transform to Azure File Share

Tags: azure-storage, mulesoft, mule4

Simple flow to fetch xml and send it back to Azure File Share after adding date to it. I'm using [Azure Storage Connector](https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange/org.mule.modules/azure-storage-connector/).

[image: Payload after Download file from root directory]

[image: Payload after Set Payload]

[image: Payload after Transform Message]

Upload file in root directory with stream fails with following error:

```
ERROR 2020-07-30 10:44:15,756 [[MuleRuntime].uber.03: [azure_test].azure_testFlow.BLOCKING @7dde3fa] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.exception.OnErrorPropagateHandler: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : File length must be greater than 0 bytes.
Element               : azure_testFlow/processors/6 @ azure_test:azure_test.xml:33 (Upload file in root directory with stream)
Element DSL           : <azure-storage:upload-file-in-root-directory-with-stream doc:name="Upload file in root directory with stream" doc:id="93b6bb01-c42c-454a-aaca-3c3325534b5d" config-ref="Azure_Storage_Config" target="payload">
                        <azure-storage:rootfile fileName="output" fileStream="#[payload]" shareName="dev"></azure-storage:rootfile>
                        </azure-storage:upload-file-in-root-directory-with-stream>
Error type            : MULE:UNKNOWN
FlowStack             : at azure_testFlow(azure_testFlow/processors/6 @ azure_test:azure_test.xml:33 (Upload file in root directory with stream))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As the pictures show the payload is in quotes after the first two processors (not counting loggers). After Transform Message however the quotes are gone and when I click Update value... it's empty. Does this mean the output payload after Transform Message isn't in the stream anymore? If so how can I make transform output a stream if possible at all? The Logger after the transform writes the new payload in the console though.

Edit:

Here's the input file:

```
<data>DATA</data>
```

XML of the flow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:azure-storage="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/azure-storage"
    xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file"
    xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/azure-storage http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/azure-storage/current/mule-azure-storage.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd">
    <azure-storage:config name="Azure_Storage_Config" doc:name="Azure Storage Config" doc:id="ced6e7d8-da1c-4d1e-b02c-fb990de78ed1" >
        <azure-storage:sas-token-config-connection accountName="account" sasToken="token"/>
    </azure-storage:config>
    <flow name="azure_testFlow" doc:id="bcb34135-5d34-4fd8-b794-1a6a668d6f53" >
        <azure-storage:download-file-from-root-directory doc:name="Download file from root directory" doc:id="c3893681-5489-4ee0-8058-38b189895a01" config-ref="Azure_Storage_Config">
            <azure-storage:root-file fileName="input" shareName="dev" />
        </azure-storage:download-file-from-root-directory>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="183d3636-9ef6-4fb0-b144-c880949dda36" message='#[payload]'/>
        <set-payload value="#[payload]" doc:name="Set Payload" doc:id="20769233-90e1-4c5c-9556-b8e582cd638c" mimeType="application/xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="62d02465-952a-4de2-9c9d-a8319f3ddb96" message="#[payload]" />
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="04150311-2a96-4215-b252-07a36c3b133e" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/xml writeDeclaration=false
--- 
{
    data: payload.data ++ now() as String {format: "yyyyMMddHHmm"}
}]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
            <ee:variables >
            </ee:variables>
        </ee:transform>
        <azure-storage:upload-file-in-root-directory-with-stream doc:name="Upload file in root directory with stream" doc:id="9a2f25b6-270f-4cff-bc87-141d7e30147e" config-ref="Azure_Storage_Config">
                    <azure-storage:rootfile fileName="outputStream" fileStream="#[payload]" shareName="dev" />
                </azure-storage:upload-file-in-root-directory-with-stream>
        <file:write doc:name="Write" doc:id="f3dc6f68-06aa-4755-b9a6-09cad8224fb7" path="C:\Users\jespe\outputFile" />
        <azure-storage:upload-file-in-root-directory doc:name="Upload file in root directory" doc:id="2ccac879-d196-41e1-8a64-58494421ee68" config-ref="Azure_Storage_Config">
            <azure-storage:file fileName="outputFile" shareName="dev" path="C:\Users\jespe\outputFile" />
        </azure-storage:upload-file-in-root-directory>
        <file:delete doc:name="Delete" doc:id="852758e7-94e6-43e2-9421-285f1bb85f26" path="C:\Users\jespe\outputFile" />
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Removed the logger before Upload file with stream. Debugger still shows the payload like that after the transform.

[image: Without Logger]

Edit 2:

The answer by @jan-h was indeed the solution. Setting deferred=true in the Transform Message doesn't work for me though. Had to set in the File Upload with Stream.

[image: Solution]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

juast add deferred=true to the last dataweave.
Like this : output application/xml deferred=true

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the last DataWeave transformation returned a non repeatable stream, so it was consumed in the logger. Try removing the last logger to see if the payload appears.

It would be better if you shared the XML of the flow. It is not possible to understand what it is doing from the screenshots alone.